# Lightswitch insert row in a grid (after selected row)

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Issue is that I have wrote a method to duplicate selected row in a grid.
Method likes (Grid is binded to `my_query`):

```
Namespace LightSwitchApplication

    Public Class Assignacions_GR_a_DPT_o_IR_manuals

        Private Sub Dup_row_Execute()
            Dim mySelectedItem = Me.my_query.SelectedItem
            Dim newItem = Me.my_query.AddNew()
            newItem.someProperty_1 = mySelectedItem.someProperty_1
            ...
            newItem.someProperty_n = mySelectedItem.someProperty_n
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

All runs fine. But new row appears at the end of the grid insteat below selected item.

My question:

> Is there a way to duplicated row appears just below source row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not, that's just the way it works. The only way that you could get the result you want (with the built-in grid) is to refresh the grid collection (in your case Me.my_uqery.Refresh).

There are a couple of things to note about that approach:

1. The SelectedItem probably won't be the same (from memory it'll be the first row)
2. The visual aspect of the refreshing *may* be disconcerting to users (then again, it may not)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yann, this helps to don't waste more time looking for a solution with built-in grid. Do you have some lightswitch app in production environment?

Comment: I have several that I use myself (harshest critic that I have, lol), plus one currently being worked on for a client.